# Schedule R script using cron

Tags: r, cron

I am trying to schedule my R script using cron, but it is not working. It seems R can not find packages in cron. Anyone can help me? Thanks.

The following is my bash script

```
# source  my profile
. /home/winie/.profile
# script.R will load packages
R CMD BATCH /home/script.R
```

Comment: This is a cross post from r-help -1

Comment: @TylerRinker, would it have been okay if OP had cross-linked in both places? I generally try to use r-help, but sometimes people do not answer and then I've added it here with a bounty.

Comment: It's ok to post in two places just link each post on different sites or help lists back to the other so someone isn't solving a problem that's already been solved.

Comment: @TylerRinker, good point. Thanks for responding!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Consider these tips

1. Use Rscript (or littler) rather than `R CMD BATCH`
2. Make sure the cron job is running as you
3. Make sure the script runs by itself
4. Test it a few times in verbose mode

My box is running the somewhat visible [CRANberries](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/cranberries/) via a cronjob calling an R script 
(which I execute via [littler](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/littler.html) but Rscript
should work just as well).  For this, the entry in `/etc/crontab` on my Ubuntu server is

```
# every few hours, run cranberries
16 */3 * * *    edd     cd /home/edd/cranberries && ./cranberries.r
```

so every sixteen minutes past every third hour, a shell command is being run with my id.  It changes into the working directory, and call the R script (which has executable modes etc).

Looking at this, I could actually just run the script and have `setwd()` command in it....

Comment: This is intriguing...can you post the R line of code to use to setwd(). I mean, how to pass the parameter from command line?

Comment: It's a fixed parameter here:  `setwd("/home/edd/cranberries"); ...rest of script...`.  But look into [doctopt](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/docopt/index.html) for command-line parameter processing...