# function that makes my loop to run after every x mins

Tags: r

I want a r function which makes my loop to run after evey 5 mins.
I have a loop that downloads market data from google finance.I want this loop to run in the interval of every 30 mins.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative to making your script loop: use an external job scheduling tool to call your script over the desired interval. If you have linux, I recommend checking out `cron`. Here's a SO response describing how to set up a cron job to kick off an R script: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10116439/819544

Comment: This is a helpful route, especially if you're using multiple R instances or are persisting the data to disk between runs (Which you should be doing).

Comment: For smaller intervals I would use Sys.sleep() but if its 5 mins or 30 mins better use a scheduler like cron or Task scheduler in windows

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Sys.sleep(100)` to stop execution for 100 seconds. It's a little inefficient vs. running some other process in the same instance and setting up a proper timer. But it's pretty easy.