# twitteR package skipping tweets?

Tags: r, twitter

I'm attempting to use the twitteR package to scrape a series of public Twitter profiles and then collect those tweets into a database. The issue I'm running into is that the API doesn't seem to be collecting the totality of the tweets available.

Here is my code:

```
library(RColorBrewer)
library(NLP)
library(twitteR)
library(foreign)
library(wordcloud)
library(tm)
library(base64enc)
library(httr)

access_token<-"" #not including these, but the oauth works for me
access_secret<-""
consumer_key<-""
consumer_secret<-"" 

###Scrapes Twitter Account

setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_secret)
set.seed(123)
user.tweets<-userTimeline('@HillaryClinton', n=3200)
df<-twListToDF(user.tweets)
```

This code grabs 340 tweets from Hillary Clinton's twitter page. But she has over 8,000 tweets so I'm confused why it's only grabbing these. I checked the date for the earliest tweet and it's April 27th of this year. Is this an issue of the API only collecting back to that date?

I don't think **that** is the case because I also used this code on a friend's twitter profile. That collected only 106 of his 451 tweets, but it reached back all the way to 2013. Yet in that case, it was skipping some tweets he had authored (they weren't retweets).

Am I missing something in my code, is there a limitation to the userTimeline function that I'm missing, or what?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be right as it also worked for me, and actually, I have previously worked with this package and have dealt with similar problems.

After struggling too much to understand why this was happening I figured out that this is due to the API limits, check them [here](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/rate-limits). I am sure that this can be avoided so you can get more tweets. However this would imply scraping Twitter and a some more lines of code.

One way of sorting this out may be by using some timer on your for loop, for instance:

```
user.tweets<-userTimeline('@HillaryClinton', n=3200)
df<-twListToDF(user.tweets)
for(i in 1:100){
user.tweets<-userTimeline('@HillaryClinton', n=3200)
df<-rbind(user.tweets)
Sys.sleep(900)
}
```

This way every 900 seconds, 15minutes, you run a query, but you can change this timer to whatever you consider.
Or another option as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18024142/function-that-makes-my-loop-to-run-after-every-x-mins) you can run the script given a timer. I guess this way you'd obtain some repeated tweets but you can easily get rid of them by:

```
df[duplicated(df), ]
```

It's very likely that this solution may not be the ideal but this worked out for me quite decently. The point is to be a bit creative! :)

I hope it helps a bit and if anyone has any suggestion of how to improve it I will be happy to hear.

Comment: That would just pull the same responses back over and over again (until Hillary tweeted and then it would grab the new tweet, and loose the oldest tweets). You would need to work with the Max ID parameter and the Since_id Parameters. Twitter Provides some good documentation regarding this here:  https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/timelines