# Best (or good) way to display GGplots

Tags: r, linux, cron, raspberry-pi

I have created a dash board in R. From 6 weeks ago, I knew nothing/very little about R but last week I was able to complete my Version 1. The problem is now how to present this on a Raspberry Pi.

I want the R Script to run every 15 minutes for updates. The way I see it there are two ways. 
One I can run the R script from a cron job, but unless I run the R script from a native R environment it does not display the GGPlot on the screen.

Secondly I could run the R script from the cron job, output to a pdf and then run a cron job to display the pdf. Xpdf works just fine but this means that every iteration I need to kill the last iteration and then rerun Xpdf to open the file again.

The 2nd option is a work around but not very pretty. I have all the code working at this stage but I would appreciate anyone's inputs as to which route to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you used Shiny to build the dashboard you can use `invalidateLater()`. Check out the default script for it:

```
if (interactive()) {
  ui <- fluidPage(
    sliderInput("n", "Number of observations", 2, 1000, 500),
    plotOutput("plot")
  )

  server <- function(input, output, session) {

    observe({
      # Re-execute this reactive expression after 1000 milliseconds
      invalidateLater(1000, session)

      # Do something each time this is invalidated.
      # The isolate() makes this observer _not_ get invalidated and re-executed
      # when input$n changes.
      print(paste("The value of input$n is", isolate(input$n)))
    })

    # Generate a new histogram at timed intervals, but not when
    # input$n changes.
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      # Re-execute this reactive expression after 2000 milliseconds
      invalidateLater(2000)
      hist(rnorm(isolate(input$n)))
    })
  }

  shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

Source: https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/invalidateLater.html

The value of `invalidateLater()` function´s first argument is in milliseconds. 15 min is 900000 milliseconds.

EDIT: Per internal command, it is indeed possible to repeat a script in a specific time interval, it can be done in more ways([link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36086599/how-do-i-run-a-function-every-second) or [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18024142/function-that-makes-my-loop-to-run-after-every-x-mins) or others incl. `invalidateLater()` in Shiny context). Here follows an adaptation of one of them in form of an infinite loop that plots ggplot2 histogram every 6 seconds:

```
library(ggplot2)

plot_it <- function(){
  a <- rnorm(1000, mean = 50, sd = 10)
  print(summary(a)) 
  p <- ggplot()+geom_histogram(aes(x=a), bins=40)
  print(p)
}

repeat {
  startTime <- Sys.time()
  plot_it()
  sleepTime <- startTime - Sys.time()+ 6
  if (sleepTime > 0)
    Sys.sleep(sleepTime)
}
```

Comment: Sorry - I did not use Shiny - just GGPlot2

Comment: If u don't mind me asking in what way did u create the dashboard only with ggplot2? Usually when one speaks of dashboard in R it is synonymous to use shiny concept. At least for me. For inner R time interval repeat you can also use the 'repeat' function

Comment: Sorry if it is TMI but just for completeness. I connect to a MySQL database and extract information. I use R to do a little arithmetic on the numbers. Then I use GGPlot to create a number of plots, which then get arranged in a grid. I have text & a logo which are converted to grobs to get arranged.

Comment: Ok, so your outcome is ggplots arranged in a grid from grobs. What do you do with it? You wanna put it into a web page or you wanna save the grid as images?

Comment: It just needs to be displayed on a screen and updated every 15 minutes or so. I am also trying to see if I can vert the plots into a format to display in Shiny

Comment: then you can use a loop with `Sys.sleep` command. I used a repeat loop in the EDIT. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a try