# R- Get script to run every X minutes regardless of execution time.

Tags: r

I have a function of variable execution time, but is going to be under 20 seconds for most use cases. I want a script to execute the function every 10 minutes regardless of how long the function actually takes (therefore cannot use the sleep command or any 'wait' command)

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793389/scheduling-r-script) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116411/schedule-r-script-using-cron)

Comment: Not on a Windows OS or have an MS tools available. Ideally I'd like this to work with red Hat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your loop:

```
p1 <- Sys.time()
yourFunct()
theDelay <- 600-as.numeric(difftime(Sys.time(),p1,unit="secs"))
Sys.sleep(max(0, theDelay)
```

or add relevant handling when the function takes > 10 minutes, if you don't want it to immediately run again

Comment: Thanks. It should never take longer than 10 minutes unless there is massive user error.

Comment: @knowads Then you should probably do if (theDelay <= 0) stop("Massive User Error!!!") or something like that.