# R code onto website, run code automatically and publish results daily?

Tags: r, publish, integrate, vs-web-site-project

I am pretty new to coding in general, therefore bear with me if this is a rookie question. I have a R code that I want to be automatically run, this R code generates some results which I want to publish onto a website daily. What is the easiest way to do so?

Comment: If you want to embrace `R` you could look into the `shiny` package for creating [web based applications](https://shiny.rstudio.com/).

Comment: what operating system are you running?

Comment: @NateDay The operating system that I use is MacOS

Comment: you probably want to use "crontab": here are two links that may help you get started https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116411/schedule-r-script-using-cron  https://ole.michelsen.dk/blog/schedule-jobs-with-crontab-on-mac-osx.html

Answer (score 0):

This is mainly a question on scheduling the R Scripts. [Scheduling R Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793389/scheduling-r-script)

Then you can feed the data into your webpage (e.g. from a csv).