# Run R Script for specified time interval

Tags: r, dataframe

Below is my sample data frame `mydf`, actual length of my data frame is unknown because it will be updated with a new row for every `10 seconds`. Also I have created empty data frames `da`, `db`, `dc`, `dd`.

```
    Vin   LA    LN
      A   98    89
      B    7    98
      C    5    89
      D   23    74
      A   81    23
      A   28    37
      B   34    48
```

Now I need to implement a logic where I should be retrieving the data from the data frame `mydf` and push it to respective data frame based on the value of `mydf$Vin` i.e `IF Vin == A`, then respective row data at `LA` and `LN`should be  pushed to the data frame `da`, similarly, `IF VIN == B` then data of `LA`& `LN` -> `db`. This script of validating the value in `Vin` and pushing the data to the respective data frame should execute for every `11 Seconds`.

For ex. If the script is executed at `Time = Current_Second` then again the script should re-run  at `Time = Current_Second + 11`.

Comment: for loop with Sys.sleep ... for example

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's easier to put da,db,dc and dd in a list. Not necessary but your for-loop becomes more legible.

```
# sample data
df = read.table(text="Vin   LA    LN
A   98    89
B    7    98
C    5    89
D   23    74
A   81    23
A   28    37
B   34    48",header=T)

# a list of your dataframes.
your_df = list(A= data.frame(LA= numeric(0), LN= numeric(0)),
               B= data.frame(LA= numeric(0), LN= numeric(0)),
               C= data.frame(LA= numeric(0), LN= numeric(0)),
               D= data.frame(LA= numeric(0), LN= numeric(0))
)

for(i in 1:nrow(df))
{
  your_df[[df$Vin[i]]] = rbind(your_df[[df$Vin[i]]], df[i,c("LA","LN")])  
  Sys.sleep(11) # set this to the desired amount of time between iterations.
  print(your_df) # optional to show progress.
}
```

Output:

```
$A
  LA LN
1 98 89
5 81 23
6 28 37

$B
  LA LN
2  7 98
7 34 48

$C
  LA LN
3  5 89

$D
  LA LN
4 23 74
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Sys.sleep` do something like this:

```
repeat {
  # Your code goes here
  cat("Hello, again!\n")

  Sys.sleep(11) # Wait 11 seconds
}
# Hello, again!
# Hello, again!
# ...
```

Alternatively, you should probably avoid doing a `for`-loop or `repeat` like above, and execute your program every X seconds from outside R. See [e.g. this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116411/schedule-r-script-using-cron/10116439#10116439)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following approach:

```
# Define interval in seconds

interval <- 11
strt_tme <- Sys.time()


repeat {
    if (Sys.time() - strt_tme > interval) {
        strt_tme <- Sys.time()
        print(paste("Start time:", strt_tme,
                    "Current time:", Sys.time()))
    }
}
```

## Notes

Contrary to `Sys.sleep` it would execute the desired command on every occasion if the time interval is greater than the desired number of seconds. If your data is updated every 11 second but reading table takes 1 minute you may be willing to execute next refresh, *immediately after* the previous refresh hence it may be safer to do calculations on system time than use 'Sys.sleep which in practice gives you: `operations time + Sys.sleep(11) = your actual interval`. The proposed approach reflects logic: *wait **at least** 11 second `(interval)`, if the the data read takes more than that then repeat immediately*. I presume that the final choice depends on how you want to refresh your data but now you have different solutions to choose from.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use `proc.time` command to set interval, you can define the time you want to